# How to input integer 2d array fast

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader

I have to input 5 int arrays, in less than 3 sec, means execution time should be less than 3,and i was using   Scanner class or that,but it is making the execution time more,so is there any other possible way,i have to get input as

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
10 11 12
13 14 15
```

And have to input 1 2 3 in one line ?how would i do it..?
i was taking initially string as input ,and then using split(" ") method for separating it,then parsing it using wrapper classes? any other way to do it?

Comment: What is your code? Scanner should not take 3 seconds, that is a long time for doing that kind of process.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following snippet, I guess its what you may be looking for inputting 2d array **without** splitting the string using Scanner..

```
    int[][] array = new int[5][2];
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int i=0;
    int k=0;
    while(scan.hasNextInt()){

        array[i][k] = scan.nextInt();

        k++;

        if(k == 2) {
            k = 0;
            i++;
        }

        if(i == array.length){
            break;
        }
    }

    for(int p=0; p < array.length; p++) {

        for(int j=0;j < 2; j++) {           
            System.out.print(array[p][j] + " ");
        }
    }
```